# Getting Database URL dynamically with Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been trying to point my Sequelize instance to a PostgreSQL database URI which I want to fetch it dynamically.

I've tried the solution below, but it seems to be not working.

```
sequelize.beforeConnect(async config => {
    config = await getDbUrl();
  });
```

Appreciate it if someone could tell me how it should be done.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `sequelize-cli` and have a `config/config.json`, setting `"use_environment_variable"` to `"YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE_HERE"` will make it dynamically set the database to the environment variable.
Example: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/784

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

That solution didn't fit my situation, but I figured out a way.